# read_parquet in jupyter throws "Invalid parquet file. Corrupt footer" error

Tags: python, jupyter, parquet

I load a freshly updated parquet file from AWS S3 in an jupyter notebook. After each update on the data in the parquet file, I get an "Invalid parquet file. Corrupt footer." error.  After each update of the parquet file the error shows up.

```
import pandas as pd

bucket = 'xxx'
path = 'xxx'
filename = 'xxx.parquet'

location = f"s3://{bucket}/{path}/{filename}"

frame1 = pd.read_parquet(location, engine = 'pyarrow')
frame1 = frame1.reset_index()
```

I would expect to get the updated dateframe with the updated data of the updated parquet file, without the need to restart the kernel. Is jupyter caching my file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to have changed with respect to caching from `s3fs==0.2.2` to `s3fs==0.3.0`, which elicits this behavior.

Going back to to `s3fs==0.2.2` solved the problem for me.